# List wrapping for finding distance between indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a random generated list that could look like:

```
[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I need to find all of the distance between the 1's including the ones that wrap around.

For an example the list above, the first 1 has a distance of 3 to the next 1. The second 1 has a distance of 1 to the following 1 and so on.

How do I find the distance for the last 1 in the list using wrap around to the first 1?

```
def calc_dist(loc_c):
   first = []
   #lst2 = []
   count = 0
   for i in range(len(loc_c)):
       if loc_c[i] == 0:
           count += 1
           #lst2.append(0)
       elif loc_c[i] == 1:
           first.append(i)
           count += 1
           loc_c[i] = count
           #lst2.append(loc_c[i])
           #if loc_c[i] + count > len(loc_c):
               # x = loc_c[first[0] + 11 % len(loc_c)]
               # loc_c[i] = x
           count = 0

   return loc_c
```

My expected outcome should be [3, 1, 2, 4].

Comment: So the 'distance' is the difference in indices between the current `1` and the next to the right? Just store the index of the first `1`, that's the distance from the end. If the last 1 is not at the end, add that much tot he distance.

Comment: If in this case it is `4` then, Find index of first `1` and index of last `1` then your result will be lengthOfList-index of last `1` +index of first `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice and tidy:

```
def calc_dist(l):
    idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(l) if v]
    if not idx: return []
    idx.append(len(l)+idx[0])
    return [idx[i]-idx[i-1] for i in range(1,len(idx))]

print(calc_dist([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
# [3, 1, 2, 4]
print(calc_dist([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
# [3, 1, 2, 7]
print(calc_dist([0, 0, 0, 0])
# []
```

Comment: I will select this as the best answer because it is nice, tidy and easy to understand for other people as well.

Comment: It's not yet perfect, because I don't know what you want to do if there is only *one* `1`. E.g. `[0, 1, 0]` will return `3` which is probably not what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Store the index of the first `1` you first reference, then when you get to the *last* `1` you only have to add the index of the first plus the number of `0` elements after the last `1` to get that distance (so `len(inputlist) - lastindex + firstindex`).

The other distances are the difference between the preceding `1` value and the current index.

```
from typing import Any, Generator, Iterable

def distances(it: Iterable[Any]) -> Generator[int, None, None]:
    """Produce distances between true values in an iterable.

    If the iterable is not endless, the final distance is that of the last
    true value to the first as if the sequence of values looped round.

    """
    first = prev = None
    length = 0
    for i, v in enumerate(it):
        length += 1
        if v:
            if first is None:
                first = i
            else:
                yield i - prev
            prev = i
    if first is not None:
        yield length - prev + first
```

The above generator calculates distances as it loops over the sequence `seq`, yielding them one by one:

```
>>> for distance in distances([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]):
...     print(distance)
...
3
1
2
4
```

Just call `list()` on the generator if you must have list output:

```
>>> list(distances([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]))
[3, 1, 2, 4]
```

If there are no `1` values, this results in zero distances yielded:

```
>>> list(distances([0, 0, 0]))
[]
```

and 1 `1` value gives you 1 distance:

```
>>> list(distances([1, 0, 0]))
[3]
```

I've made the solution generic enough to be able to handle *any iterable*, even if infinite; this means you can use another generator to feed it too. If given an infinite iterable that produces at least *some* non-zero values, it'll just keep producing distances.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
id = np.where(test == 1)[0]

# id = array([0, 3, 4, 6], dtype=int64)

res = [id[i]-id[i-1] for i in range(1, len(id))]
# [3, 1, 2]

# Last distance missing:
res.append(len(L)- id[-1])

res = [3, 1, 2, 4]
```

Note that the information you ask for is comprised above, but maybe the output format is wrong. You were not really specific...

*Edit: How to convert list to an array since you generate random list*

```
L = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
np.asarray(L)
```

*Edit2: How to check if there is no 1 in the list:*

```
import numpy as np

L = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
id = np.where(test == 1)[0]

if len(id) == 0:
    res = []
else:
    res = [id[i]-id[i-1] for i in range(1, len(id))]
    res.append(len(L)- id[-1])
```

OR:

```
try:
    res = [id[i]-id[i-1] for i in range(1, len(id))]
    res.append(len(L)- id[-1])
except:
    res = []
```

Comment: @PM2Ring I've done that part: "For an example the list above, the first 1 has a distance of 3 to the next 1. The second 1 has a distance of 1 to the following 1 and so on.". The other one I don't really get what he wants.

Comment: No, you don't, you need **4** distances, you are missing the last distance of 4.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok I didn't get it on the first read. Fixed in the edit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would be curious to time both your solution with a generator and mine with numpy and see which perform best :)

Comment: Mine is a generator loop of interpreted bytecode, yours is based on hand-optimised native compiled code in numpy. I think I know where that is going ;-)